# Python passing variable values via import

Tags: python

I want to use a variable that I assigned in another file, is there a way that the import of that variable from that file will maintain the value of the variable?

Comment: `from my_file import my_variable`?

Comment: yes. for example if a variable `x` in a file say `test.py`, you can import it in another file like `import test`, `test.x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a variable `my_variable` in a module called `my_module.py` and it has been initialized, you can access to it from another module:

```
from my_module import my_variable
```

You can also do:

```
import my_module
...
my_module.my_variable
```

but I recommend the first option if you only need that variable from `my_module.py`

Answer (score 0):

If a file `ham.py` contains:

```
eggs = 1
```

Then in `spam.py` you can say:

```
from ham import eggs
print eggs
```

Or:

```
import ham
print ham.eggs
```